# Asignar matriz propia a diferentes clientes PSEINT

Tags: pseint

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que debo ingresar unas medidiones de glucosa, antes de empezar debo introducir la cantidad de pacientes a ingresar luego debo registrar el nombre y numero de cedula del paciente, posteriormente llenar los datos de las mediciones en una matriz[6,2], luego mostrar los datos de cada paciente, el problema es que no se como hacer para que cada matriz tenga los respectivos datos de cada paciente ya que a como lo tengo logra mostrar los pacientes con sus respectivos números de cedula pero los datos de la matriz de todos son los mismos o sea solo me agarra los datos del ultimo paciente que ingrese: este es el código por si alguien me puede ayudar:

```
Proceso principal
Escribir matriz();
FinProceso
SubProceso medicion <- matriz()
Definir k,j,arreglo,i,N,C como entero;
Definir P Como caracter;
Dimension arreglo[6,2];
Dimension P[40];
Dimension C[12];
Escribir "Introduza la cantidad de pacientes a registrar";
Leer N;

Para i<-0 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir "Introduzca el nombre del paciente";
   Leer P[i];
    Escribir "Introduzca la cédula del paciente";
   Leer C[i];
Para k<-0 Hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para j<-0 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Introduzca primero la medición prepandial, luego la posprandial, en ese orden";
        Leer arreglo[k,j];
    FinPara
FinPara
FinPara

Para i<-0 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
Para k<-0 Hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para j<-0 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
Escribir "El paciente ",P[i]," cédula ",C[i]," ",arreglo[k,j];
    FinPara
FinPara
FinPara
FinSubProceso
```

Answer (score 2):

Es que necesitas un arreglo mas grande para introducir los datos de todos los pacientes, y con un contador guardas la posición en donde se quedó el último numero del arreglo, algo así:
Proceso principal
    Escribir matriz();
FinProceso
SubProceso medicion <- matriz()
    Definir k,j,arreglo,i,N,C,l como entero;
    Definir P Como caracter;

```
Dimension arreglo[72,2];
Dimension P[12];
Dimension C[12];
k<-0;
l<-0;
Escribir "Introduzca la cantidad de pacientes a registrar";
Leer N;
Para i<-0 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir "Introduzca el nombre del paciente";
    Leer P[i];
    Escribir "Introduzca la cédula del paciente";
    Leer C[i];
    Escribir "Introduzca las seis mediciones prepandiales";
    n<-1;
    Para k<-l Hasta l+5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Introduzca la medición ",n;
        Leer arreglo[k,0];
        n<-n+1;
    FinPara
    n<-1;
    Escribir "Introduzca las seis mediciones postpandiales";
    Para k<-l Hasta l+5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Introduzca la medición ",n;
        Leer arreglo[k,1];
        n<-n+1;
    FinPara
    k<-l;
FinPara
```

con el contador "l" llevo donde va el numero del arreglo.
Espero te sirva